# Imprimir elementos de uma matriz

Tags: python, matriz, tkinter

Opa, estou tentando escrever um código que abre caixas para eu colocar elementos de uma matriz de ordem 2, coloco os elementos e aperto o botão para imprimir mas simplesmente não imprime nada, ele deixa a linha vazia e pula para a próxima.

```
import numpy as np

from numpy import linalg

from tkinter import *

janela = Tk()

janela.title("Determinante e Matriz identidade")

janela.geometry("650x500+120+120")
janela.configure(bg='bisque2')

elementos_matriz = []

class print1: 
    def print(self):
        for i in range(0, 4):
            print(elementos_matriz[i] )


matriz = np.zeros((2,2))
    
for l in range(0, 2):
    for c in range(0, 2):   
                
        elementos = Entry(janela, width=4)
        elementos.grid(row=6+l, column=5+c)

        elementos_matriz.append(elementos.get())


button = Button(janela, text="Ir", bg="white", command=print)
button.grid(row=3, column=4)

janela.mainloop()
```

Eu não conheço python e a linguagem que eu mais conheço é C e só vi até matrizes hehehe.

Comment: Pra que criar uma classe? Uma função simples já resolve. E também dá para ajustar outras coisas, sugestão: https://replit.com/@hkotsubo/tkinterMatrix#main.py

Answer (score -3):

Tens que instanciar a classe do print. Podes usar a matriz de zeros para definir os valores por defeito. Depois tens que adicionar a textbox à lista e no print chamar o método get().

```
import numpy as np

from numpy import linalg

from tkinter import *

janela = Tk()

janela.title("Determinante e Matriz identidade")

janela.geometry("650x500+120+120")
janela.configure(bg='bisque2')

elementos_matriz = []

class print1: 
    def print(self):
        for i in range(0, 4):
            print(elementos_matriz[i].get())


matriz = np.zeros((2,2))
    
for l in range(0, 2):
    for c in range(0, 2):   
        value = str(int(matriz[l][c]))
        elementos = Entry(janela, width=4)
        elementos.insert(0, value)
        elementos.grid(row=6+l, column=5+c)
        elementos_matriz.append(elementos)

p = print1()

button = Button(janela, text="Ir", bg="white", command=p.print)
button.grid(row=3, column=4)

janela.mainloop()
```